# Ordinal Regression, warning and small sample size

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spss, ordinal-data

I have a model with a ordinal dependent variable: low, medium, high (coded as 1,2,3).

There are around 13% data with 1, 55% with 2, 32% with 3)

$n=200$ and there are 10 continuous predictor variables.

I carried out ordinal regression. But since $n$ is relatively small, dependent variable has 3 variations and data in one category(1) is low, it is giving some warnings (SPSS):

```
There are xx cells (i.e., dependent variable levels by observed combinations of predictor variable values) with zero frequencies.
```

The data were collected using survey. So, I cannot start data collection again and add data (as it is time bound study).  And I found it is virtually impossible to eliminate those warnings with out adding cases (rows).

In goodness of fit:

```
pearson   Sig   0.005
deviance   Sig  1.00
```

Deviance significance is good but pearson is not.

**I am trying to investigate significance (p value) and relation (effect) of each predictor variable on dependent variable.**

So, what can or should I do or what can be done?

Can I ignore the warning and use the model and significance?

As an alternative:
I carried out multiple regression every thing is fine. 8 variables are found the be significant.  Model significance is less 0.05 (good).

Can I go with it? Totally stuck.

Answer (score 1):

SPSS' warning shows that SPSS does not understand ordinal models.  Individual cell sizes do not matter as long as you are using the equal slopes assumption (e.g., proportional odds).  But your overall sample size is only large enough to have 1 or 2 candidate predictors.  96 observations are needed just to estimate a single, simple proportion to within a margin of error of +/- 0.1 with 0.95 confidence.

Don't use the goodness of fit assessments you are using.  These don't work here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. As  a part of academic research, I have to complete it. So, what can i do then? Do I continue with multiple regression, in such case the examiner may ask, why don't you use ordinal regression(or if I can use multi regression)? Collecting 96x10 cases(survey) is out of the question for now. or Do I continue ordinal regression ignoring the warning(may not be good). Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I am thinking of changing the dependent variable as binary: low and high (removing medium) and using logistic regression. How about that?

Comment: Making an ordinal Y into a binary Y will **reduce** your effective sample size, hence make things worse.   If you don't want to get into penalized maximum likelihood estimation, I advise you to use a data reduction method (unsupervised learning) to reduce the X space down to one or two columns (e.g., principal component analysis).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did the principal component analysis and got those 10 factors or predictors  as a result. Each factor has many items with in them i.e. continuous scalar predictor variable  is a mean of items. I did binaary logistic regression everything is looking good but yes now two lower categories has been merged into one.

Comment: Show the detailed steps on how you "got those 10 factors".  And your sample size does not allow for 10 variables even if they were fully pre-specified.  And DON'T merge categories.

Comment: Thank you. So what are my options? Since it is academic research with time limitations, I don't think i will be able to collect more data and data pattern will change much. So what can I do? Do I still use ordinal regression and ignore the warning or I opt for multiple regression instead. What can be most logical thing considering my case? thank you

Comment: Choose a model that makes maximum use of the data, and don't switch models for no reason.  State what is your burning research question then translate it to variables and I may be able to help a bit more.  And finally, please don't ignore previous issues.  How many variables did you start with and exactly what were the steps to get to 10 predictors.  It seems that your project is quite statistical but you don't want to invest the time to learn the important statistical issues necessary to understand for your research.